# When using false leads when foreshadowing something, how do you maintain narrative coherence?

Tags: creative-writing, narrative, foreshadowing, consistency

When using false leads when foreshadowing something, how do you maintain narrative coherence? I want to make people believe that the lead character is the killer by giving false leads when foreshadowing. I have written scenes where it seems like I am foreshadowing a betrayal of a number of different characters against the main group of protagonists, but I am wondering how I can do this without negatively impacting narrative coherence.

Do these false leads, for example, needs to be explained so that the readers don't think it was a mistake from the reader, or do you allow them to fill in the blanks and make them figure it out on their own?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? Is the problem that you think that readers will feel cheated when they get to the reveal? Are you worried that your clues pointing to the truth might seem like mistakes? Or something else?